# Error in pagination after upgrading laravel to 5.4 from 5.2

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5.4

```
public function listdata() {

$locale = Input::get('locale');
$pageSize = intval(Input::get('pageSize'));
$currentPage = intval(Input::get('currentPage'));
$column = Input::get('column');
$sort_type = Input::get('sort_type');

$search_key = Input::get('search_key');

$default_locale = Config('config.default_locale');

Paginator::currentPageResolver(function () use ($currentPage) {
    return $currentPage;
});

$var = User::orderBy($column, $sort_type)->paginate($pageSize);

...further code
```

I was using this in laravel 5.2 and it was working fine. But after upgrading to laravel 5.4 I am getting the error in pagination everywhere in my project.

```
(1/1) BindingResolutionException
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $items ]] in 
class Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
```

I have seen many answers related to this problem but nothing helps me. Any help is appreciated and please don't write any link because I have already tried many.

Comment: please show your blade code that how you rendering paginate data

Comment: I am not rendering it using blade

Comment: instead I am returning the data to angular API and then processingit

Comment: $var = User::orderBy($column, $sort_type)->paginate($pageSize); this is the line throwing the error... the paginator() function

Comment: If you are returning data then you will need to return it. Have you tried to add a ```->get();``` call after the paginate?

Comment: i have tried get but it's still not working sir

Comment: I am looking for answer friend .. I have already told i have seen some posts but not satisfied